# How to setup digital signatures on Microsoft CA (AD-CS)?

Tags: certificate, certificate-authority, ad-certificate-services

I've been trying to research across the web on how to setup a Microsoft CA (AD-CS on Windows Server 2008 R2) in order to create a certificate for digital signatures, allowing you to digitally sign emails. There are lots of articles on how to configure Outlook once you have a certificate, but not many on how to create the certificate on AD-CS.

Is this possible and if so, how do you go about doing this?

I've checked also http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754490.aspx but accessing the CertSrv web page and it only allows me to create a 'User Certificate'.

Comment: I believe that the user certificate template provides the email signing usage...

Comment: Ah ok! Let me try that!